# Retrieve sensor data from Samsung Smart watch

Tags: tizen

As part of my master thesis I need to get access to sensor data in Samsung smart watch. The OS of watch is Tizen.
I want to use codes in this post from tizen forum:

https://developer.tizen.org/community/code-snippet/native-code-snippet/read-heart-rate-monitor-data

In tizen studio I went to File > New> New Tizen Poject> Sample> Wearable 5.5> Web Application> then in Application Samples, I choose Sensor , then I choose Hart Rate Monitor. I attached the screen shot.
Now my question is: In which file of project I must write the codes from forum?

I attached the folders of the created project. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiYQJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select application type before getting sensor data. **Tizen Studio** supports Native (C language) application and Web application. **Visual Studio with Tizen Plugin** supports .NET application. Native samples: https://docs.tizen.org/development/sample/native/ Web Samples: https://docs.tizen.org/development/sample/web/Sensor C#(.NET) Samples: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen-CSharp-Samples/tree/master/Wearable/Xamarin.Forms

Comment: I chose Web application. And I used these codes:

Answer (score 0):

I chose Web Application. I followed codes in Tizen website:

```
var HRMrawsensor = tizen.sensorservice.getDefaultSensor("HRM_RAW");

 function onGetSuccessCB(sensorData) {
     console.log("HRMRaw light intensity : " + sensorData.lightIntensity);
 }

 function onerrorCB(error) {
     console.log("error occurs");
 }

 function onsuccessCB() {
     console.log("HRMRaw sensor start");
     HRMrawsensor.getHRMRawSensorData(onGetSuccessCB, onerrorCB);
 }

 HRMrawsensor.start(onsuccessCB);
```

Now, how can I find saved sensor datas? I need these data to be transfered to my computer.